# on res._renderHeaders function in connect module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am studying the patch.js in connect module. There are some code as follows:

```
var http = require('http')
  , res = http.ServerResponse.prototype
  , setHeader = res.setHeader
  , _renderHeaders = res._renderHeaders
    ...

res._renderHeaders = function(){
    if (!this._emittedHeader) this.emit('header');
    this._emittedHeader = true;
    return _renderHeaders.call(this);
  };
```

I'm confused by this strange code on res._renderHeaders function definition. In the return, it is calling itself ? so will it call itself recursively ? or what is the correct running process ?

The similar cases are also arised for res.writeHead, res._renderHeaders .

Answer (score 0):

It's not calling itself, it's calling the previous implementation:

```
// store reference to 'old' implementation
_renderHeaders = res._renderHeaders;
...
// create a new implementation
res._renderHeaders = function(){
  ...
  // which calls the old implementation
  return _renderHeaders.call(this);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your indication. However, where is the old implementation? Is it in nodejs ? but I cannot find the description of _renderHeaders property in the API doc of nodejs.

Comment: It's a method of a class called `OutgoingMessage`, [defined in the http.js module](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.8-release/lib/http.js#L747). I guess it's not documented because it's not an exposed API (in the sense that end users should be using it).

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Previously I downloaded the source code of Nodejs in "master" branch instead of "v0.10.8-release" from Github

Comment: and the http.js file in master branch is too early to have such methods. It seems I should download the newest version in the branch, but which version is the correct version that I should download ? Is this information from the wiki home page "Current stable version is 0.10. ...." ?

Comment: Oh, maybe I should check the version of my node.exe, and check the source code of the same version.

Comment: The master branch is the very latest (newest) version, which might be unstable to use. So I used the latest release-version (0.10.8) to link to.

Comment: // which calls the old implementation
  return _renderHeaders.call(this); this code call the old implementation with the current res (http.ServerResponse.prototype)  as "this" in the old implementation. However, if written as return _renderHeaders(), then the "this" in the old implementation will be the OutgoingMessage.prototype ?

Comment: @smallTiger no; since `var _renderHeaders` is declared at the scope of the patch module, it will be called in that scope as well. Hence the need to use `.call()` (FWIW, I think `ServerResponse` is a subclass of `OutgoingMessage`).

Answer (score 0):

OK. let's say it here more clear.
// which calls the old implementation 
return _renderHeaders.call(this);

the above code call the old implementation with the current res (http.ServerResponse.prototype) as "this" in the old implementation. 
However, if written as return _renderHeaders(), then the "this" in the old implementation will be the OutgoingMessage.prototype ?